# Puppeteer & Docker: Protocol error (Target.setAutoAttach): Target closed

Tags: dockerfile, puppeteer

I'm trying to upgrade dependencies in a Node repository that uses Puppeteer, and is served via Docker on Cloud Run. It's been a few years since I tried to do this, so this was a big jump from Puppeteer 12.0.0 to 21.0.3 (likewise a jump from node 12 to node 18).

The Puppeteer browser no longer seems to work with my setup after doing these upgrades. Host machine is an ARM64 Mac, but I get the same issues regardless of environment.

Here's the args I'm using to launch the browser in Javascript, which is also where I believe the error is coming from after isolating it:

```
const browser = await launch({
  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--font-render-hinting=none'],
  headless: 'new',
});
```

The error message I get from this action is:

```
TargetCloseError: Protocol error (Target.setAutoAttach): Target closed
    at CallbackRegistry.clear (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:138:36)
    at #onClose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:282:25)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/NodeWebSocketTransport.js:57:30)
    at callListener (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:290:14)
    at WebSocket.onClose (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:220:9)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at WebSocket.emitClose (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:258:10)
    at Socket.socketOnClose (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1264:15)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12)
performing snapshot function...
```

My Dockerfile is as follows (borrowing from both https://github.com/browserless/chrome/blob/master/base/Dockerfile and https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting#running-puppeteer-in-docker)

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV NODE_VERSION v18.12.0
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/src/.nvm
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/bin
ENV PATH $NODE_PATH:$PATH

COPY ./build-config/fonts.conf /etc/fonts/local.conf

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq dist-upgrade

RUN apt-get -y -qq install software-properties-common && \
  apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"

RUN echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get -y -qq --no-install-recommends install \
  build-essential \
  ca-certificates \
  curl \
  dumb-init \
  ffmpeg \
  fontconfig \
  fonts-freefont-ttf \
  fonts-gfs-neohellenic \
  fonts-indic \
  fonts-ipafont-gothic \
  fonts-kacst \
  fonts-liberation \
  fonts-noto-cjk \
  fonts-noto-color-emoji \
  fonts-roboto \
  fonts-thai-tlwg \
  fonts-ubuntu \
  fonts-wqy-zenhei \
  gconf-service \
  git \
  libappindicator1 \
  libappindicator3-1 \
  libasound2 \
  libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
  libatk1.0-0 \
  libc6 \
  libcairo2 \
  libcups2 \
  libdbus-1-3 \
  libexpat1 \
  libfontconfig1 \
  libgbm-dev \
  libgbm1 \
  libgcc1 \
  libgconf-2-4 \
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
  libglib2.0-0 \
  libgtk-3-0 \
  libnspr4 \
  libnss3 \
  libpango-1.0-0 \
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
  libstdc++6 \
  libu2f-udev \
  libx11-6 \
  libx11-xcb1 \
  libxcb1 \
  libxcomposite1 \
  libxcursor1 \
  libxdamage1 \
  libxext6 \
  libxfixes3 \
  libxi6 \
  libxrandr2 \
  libxrender1 \
  libxss1 \
  libxtst6 \
  locales \
  lsb-release \
  msttcorefonts \
  pdftk \
  unzip \
  wget \
  xdg-utils \
  xvfb

RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR &&\
  curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash &&\
  . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh &&\
  nvm install $NODE_VERSION

ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init

RUN fc-cache -f -v && \
  apt-get -qq clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN cp /app/fonts/*.otf /usr/share/fonts/opentype && mkfontscale && mkfontdir && fc-cache -f -v

ARG NPM_TOKEN

ENV NPM_TOKEN ${NPM_TOKEN}

RUN npm i --omit=dev

EXPOSE ${PORT}
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "/app/build/src/index.js"]
```

I think this is rooted in Chrome failing to launch, and this is a problem that I can't seem to shake. I see that by default Puppeteer installs the Chrome executable to the home path of a non-root user (/home/pptruser/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-115.0.5790.170/chrome-linux64/chrome), which isn't really what I want, but it doesn't seem to make a difference if I use that executable or an executable that I install myself via my Dockerfile.

I've tried using other base images like https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile, I've tried adding steps to my dockerfile to install chrome manually, I've tried adding commands to launch the dbus service in my dockerfile, but with all of these attempts, when I ssh into my container and try to run chrome from the command line with the above args, I always get errors like these:

```
$ google-chrome-stable --headless --no-sandbox -disable-setuid-sandbox --font-render-hinting=none --dump-dom https://developer.chrome.com
[0829/232805.405001:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0829/232805.482207:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0829/232805.482827:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0829/232805.716354:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(393)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0829/232805.721404:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
Segmentation fault
```

If I add steps to install dbus and run it in the dockerfile, the `No such file or directory` errors just turn into `Connection refused` errors.

How can I get the browser to just work again?

Comment: That sounds like permissions might be preventing chrome from accessing dbus.